# How do I specify the programs that I want to run when the computer boots ? [Arch]

Tags: arch-linux, boot, gnome, gnome3

I am currently using Arch with the GNOME desktop environment. I do not know where to specify the programs I want to run automatically when the computer boots. If there are multiple methods (GUI or non-GUI) to achieve this, I would like to know both.

Comment: you wanna run a script on boot ?

Comment: @arzyfex not really, just need specific applications up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the applications you want to automatically start when booting the system by adding them to Startup Applications in the `tweak-tool` - open the Tweak Tool from Activities launcher :

[image]

Alternatively copy a `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.config/autostart/`.

Comment: Isn't there a single file where this can be entries can be inputted? Either ways, I'll wait for more answers before I accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a `systemd` service to run your application during boot process. Create a new file in `/etc/systemd/system` (e.g. myscript.service) and add the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my-script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

put your script in `/usr/bin/my-script` and make sure to make it executable. and then enable the service.

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/my-script
$ sudo systemctl enable myscript.service
```

This example assumes you want your script to start up when the target multi-user is launched.